# Python regex to find characters inside delimiters

Tags: python, regex

I have a more challenging task, but first I am faced with this issue.  Given a string `s`, I want to extract all the groups of characters marked by some delimiter, e.g. parentheses.  How can I accomplish this using regular expressions (or any Pythonic way)?

```
import re

>>> s = '(3,1)-[(7,2),1,(a,b)]-8a'
>>> pattern = r'(\(.+\))'
>>> re.findall(pattern, s).group()            # EDITED: findall vs. search
['(3,1)-[(7,2),1,(a,b)']

# Desire result
['(3,1)', '(7,2)', '(a,b)']
```

Comment: Look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall

Comment: Also look into the concept of "greediness" in the + and * operators.

Comment: `findall` gives a similar result. I've edited the question for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `findall()` instead of `search()`. The former finds all occurences, the latter only finds the first.

Use the non-greedy `?` operator. Otherwise, you'll find a match starting at the first `(` and ending at the final `)`.

Note that regular expressions aren't a good tool for finding nested expressions like: `((1,2),(3,4))`.

```
import re
s = '(3,1)-[(7,2),1,(a,b)]-8a'
pattern = r'(\(.+?\))'
print re.findall(pattern, s)
```

Comment: Alright so my regex pattern is apparently too greedy.  I appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[re.findall()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall)**

```
import re
data = '(3,1)-[(7,2),1,(a,b)]-8a'
found = re.findall('(\(\w,\w\))', data)
print found
```

Output:

```
['(3,1)', '(7,2)', '(a,b)']
```

Comment: I suppose `\w` includes `?`